# NGINX attempts to load from /usr/share/nginx/html/*

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

my nginx after enabling SSL is trying to load from /usr/share/nginx/html/*

i have deleted default from sites-available and sites-enabled
as far as i can see there is no reference to /usr/share/nginx/html anywhere, and my ROOT variables are set correctly..

My sites-enabled are symlinks from sites-available

domain SSL

```
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
        root /var/www/mydomain/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name my_domain_here www.my_domain_here;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location ~ .+\.unityweb$ {
    add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
    }
    location ~* ^.*\.(js)$ {
            types {}
            default_type application/javascript;
            }
           
            location ~* ^.*\.(wasm)$ {
            types {}
            default_type application/wasm;
            }
            location ~* ^.*\.(wasm.gz)$ {
            gunzip on;
            gzip off;
            types {}
            default_type application/wasm;
            add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
            }
            location ~* ^.*\.(framework.js.gz|js.gz)$ {
            gunzip on;
            gzip off;
            types {}
            default_type application/javascript;
            add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
            }
           
            location ~* ^.*\.(data.gz|symbols.json.gz)$ {
            gunzip on;
            gzip off;
            types {}
            default_type application/octet-stream;
            add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
            }
gzip on;

gzip_vary on;

gzip_proxied any;

gzip_comp_level 6;

gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
}
```

Domain HTTPS redirect /etc/sites-available/domain.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my_domain_here www.my_domain_here

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}
```

my nginx.conf (entirely default no changes)

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

output from error.log

```
2021/11/17 22:47:50 [error] 105470#105470: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/unity/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: *, server: *, request: "GET /unity/ HTTP/1.1", host: "*"
2021/11/17 22:47:54 [error] 105470#105470: *3 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: *, server: *, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "*", referr>
2021/11/17 23:16:55 [error] 105470#105470: *6 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: *, server: *, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", host: "*"
```

Comment: You've redacted the error log, so you will need to check it. Which `server` generated the error? Are you testing using a browser or curl, http or https? Does `curl -I http://my_domain_here/` generate a 302 response?

Comment: Hey, the Server: is my own domain in the error logs.

I do not get a 302 response, the server gives me a 404 not found on http. 
Same with HTTPS.

Comment: ```2021/11/18 11:09:03 [warn] 611#611: server name "https://my_domain_here$request_uri" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_domain.com:6
2021/11/18 11:09:03 [warn] 611#611: "ssl_stapling" ignored, issuer certificate not found for certificate "/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt"
2021/11/18 11:11:34 [error] 613#613: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 162.158.183.134, server: my_domain_here, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", host: "my_domain_here"``` are the errors generated now. Nginx -T shows no other root than /var

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `;` off the end of the `server_name` statement, and the `return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri` line is being interpreted as more server names. Also, you will not find `/usr/share/nginx/html` in your configuration - it is the default when no `root` statement is present.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by merging the two sites-available from two separate files to one.

Not sure what the issue was, probably that i was trying to serve the same root directory and server_name in both files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).